# How to view the list of reference in a markdown file?

Tags: reference, markdown

By default we show reference in markdown file as below :

```
* [Example Grammer][example_grammer]- this is a reference
```

and bottom of the page added the reference list that are not visible in the markdown file view.

```
[example_grammer]: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.xtext.doc%2Fcontents%2F020-grammar-language.html
```

Is it possible to show the reference in the view file as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The original Markdown specification [doesn't support this](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link):

> Link definitions are only used for creating links during Markdown processing, and are stripped from your document in the HTML output.

There might be some third-party implementations of Markdown that do support this, but I'm not aware of any.